# Hydrogen Atom, polar equation eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, normalization, spherical-harmonics

In my textbook, Quantum Mechanics by David McIntyre on page 235, the solutions to the polar equation resulting from the separation of variables to the hydrogen atom are the eigenstates:
[image]

The book claims that this function is normalized, however, after changing the variables to $z=cos(\theta)$ The result was not Kronecker delta. Is there a typo in this equation or am I missing something?

Comment: [Orthogonality relations of the associated Legendre functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.17.E6).

Comment: So I assume the writer forgot to put a square root on the coefficient of the Legendre associated function?